# How to send the Anonymous type object to a method

Tags: c#, linq, frameworks, entity

I am using Linq using Entity Framework to query MySQL Database as below -

```
var query = from c in subQuery
            select new
            {
                Client = c.Client,
                GlobalList = c.GlobalList,
                Book = (from book in context.Books
                       where book.c_clt_id == c.Client.c_clt_id 
                       select book)
            };
var totalSearch = query.ToList();
```

now i want to pass totalSearch as a parameter to another method. Please help me how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the C# dynamic keyword. Of course it is a slow as reflection and type unsafe. For example:

```
void SomeMethod(dynamic d)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.Client);
    Console.WriteLine(d.GlobalList.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only *typed* way you can do that is if the other method is generic, and you let generic type inference do the work:

```
void SomeOtherMethod<T>(List<T> list) {...}
...
SomeOtherMethod(totalSearch);
```

You can also pass it *without any type information* via  `IList`, `IEnumerable`, `object` or `dynamic`, of course.

Comment: Of course the method won't be able to refer to any of the type's properties without using reflection.

Comment: @Amnon very true - but it depends what that methods wants to do. And a common trick is to pass in selectors to access members...

Comment: Can you Please guide me in how to write selectors in this case?

Comment: @Harshal for example by passing a `Func<T,TValue>` into the method and invoking it per object it the list...

Answer (score 2):

You probably should't do that. Without the type information your method won't (easily) be able to access the properties of the object.

Use a concrete user defined type instead. If your object is very short-lived and you don't want to create a new type you could use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) (requires .NET 4 or newer).

Comment: Can you Please guide me in how to write Tuple in this case?